Given start and end time of tasks build dependency graph
I have a list of tasks with start time and end time.

Task 1: start time 1, end time 3
Task 2: start time 2, end time 5
Task 3: start time 4, end time 6

Task 2 should start after task 1 has started and task 3 can start after task 1 has finished and task 2 started. How can I build a dependency graph of tasks from this information efficiently.

"How can I build a dependency graph of tasks": You just described the dependencies, so you have described the graph... no? Don't understand the question. What is holding you back?
